# CMD move command remove original file?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want move file using `cmd` on my PC with `Windows`.

I am using command:

```
MOVE SOURCE LOCATION
```

For move my library:

```
MOVE jfreechart-1.0.19.jar ../bin/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar
```

**But I dont wan't delete original file.**

I try to read doc http://ss64.com/nt/move.html but I didn't found any help.

How to do this?

Comment: Is your question _"How can I move a file while keeping the original file"_? Have you heard of "copying"?

Answer (score 2):

Just use COPY instead.

```
Syntax
      COPY [options] [/A|/B] source [/A|/B] [+ source2 [/A|/B]...] [destination [/A|/B]]

      COPY source1 + source2.. destination [options]
```

http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html

Comment: When i try: `COPY jfreechart-1.0.19.jar ../bin/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar` i get "The syntaxt of the command is incorrect". Why?

Comment: @chelorcre because you're using the wrong directory separator character for Windows.

Comment: Thank you. WORK: `COPY jfreechart-1.0.19.jar ..\bin\jfreechart-1.0.19.jar`